# Kali Linux Live CD Blackscreen/Not Booting

Tags: boot, iso-image, kali-linux, livecd

I am pretty new to Kali Linux (or Linux in general) so probably I won't understand ALL of the technical terms, but I will give my best.

As introduction in my problem, I wanted to create a Live CD with Kali Linux for my Laptop (exact information on version etc. will be given later, as well as the chronological order of the things I did).

After burning the ISO Image of Kali, I restarted my Laptop, and wanted to boot Kali Linux as a "Live Session", but everything I have seen was a Blackscreen, with no console, and no mouse pointer.

The Laptop did not react to anything, so I took out the disk, and started my PC new and booted with my primary operating system. After that I tried different things (which I will list too), but nothing of it helped me.

My System:

```
Laptop Model: ASUS R510LB-XX037H
OS: Windows 8.1 64-Bit
Architecture: 64-Bit
Processor: Intel Core i74500U CPU @ 1.80 Ghz 2.40 Ghz
RAM: 8.00 GB (7.89 Usable)
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, nVidia GEFORCE 740M
```

(If more Information is necessary I will give it)

The Linux:

```
Kali Linux
64 bit (because my System is 64x Based)
Version: 2016.1
Boot Media: Disk (DVD-RW), 4.7 GB Storage
```

=> So basically the first thing [here](https://www.kali.org/downloads/)  (Kali Linux 64 bit ISO)

The Things I did (in chronological order)

- Downloaded Linux Kali 64 bit 2016.1 ISO
- Saved on Desktop
- Took a brand new CD and put it in
- Right Clicked the ISO and burned the Image (With the Burning Option given by the System)
- Opened Charm Bar => Settings => Change PC Settings => Update/Recovery => Recovery => Advanced Start
- Selected the Option for opening the UEFI Settings
- Boot => Changed The Boot-Order, DVD will be booted first before main OS
- Restarted the PC
- Red Window saying "Secure Boot Violation" and some text, so I entered UEFI again and disabled "Secure Boot"
- Restarted PC again
- Blackscreen
- [after 20 min] manually restarted the PC (simple power-off)
- Burned ISO-Image again on fresh Disk
- Restart
- Blackscreen again
- power-off, boot with Windows again
- and so I came here

I really don't know what I can do more, under Windows everything works fine (related to Hardware).

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try [CBBurnerXP](https://www.cdburnerxp.se/). It has an option to burn ISO files. If that doesn't work, try `Universal USB Installer`, `YUMI Multiboot usb` or `LinuxLive USB Creator`. Live linux will work faster when booted via USB than from CD.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes happens that there are errors in the download process. You need to verify that the ISO file is the exact same by generating and comparing a MD5 or SHA1 hash.

In this case the SHA1Sum is posted on the downloads page of the link you provided.

You can find this link to the Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier by searching for "SHA1Sum Windows" [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)

After using your choice of SHA1Sum generator to verify that the downloaded ISO file's SHA1Sum is the same, you can then check to see if the image is being burned to disk correctly. You should use the 'verify' option when burning the disk. But what if you've already done that? How do you compare the ISO to the burned disk? It's easy with Ubuntu.

The following is from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

First mount the CD, if not already mounted:

```
sudo mount /dev/hda /cdrom
```

Then use the supplied md5sum file on the CD:

```
cd /cdrom
md5sum -c md5sum.txt | grep -vi 'OK$'
```

See also the "Check the CD" section.